# Expected an identifier and instead saw '<'

Tags: icon, svg

I am having difficulty adding a custom svg icon to my Wordpress Plugin, I read on this page https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/components/icon/ that to add a custom svg icon to my plugin for my blocks I need to add the following code to my block.js file in my plugin:

```
import { Icon } from '@wordpress/components';

const MyIcon = () => (
    <Icon icon={ <svg><path d="M5 4v3h5.5v12h3V7H19V4z" /></svg> } />
);
```

I have the following text in my block.js file:

```
( function() {
    var __ = wp.i18n.__; // The __() function for internationalization.
    var createElement = wp.element.createElement; // The wp.element.createElement() function to create elements.
    var registerBlockType = wp.blocks.registerBlockType; // The registerBlockType() function to register blocks.

    import { Icon } from '@wordpress/components';

    const MyIcon = () => (
        <Icon icon={ () => <svg><path d="M5 4v3h5.5v12h3V7H19V4z" /></svg> } />
    );

    /**
     * Register block
     *
     * @param  {string}   name     Block name.
     * @param  {Object}   settings Block settings.
     * @return {?WPBlock}          Block itself, if registered successfully,
     *                             otherwise "undefined".
     */
    registerBlockType(
        'plugin/custom-block-shortcode-block', // Block name. Must be string that contains a namespace prefix. Example: my-plugin/my-custom-block.
        {
            title: __( 'custom-block', 'plugin-blocks' ), // Block title. __() function allows for internationalization.
            icon: MyIcon,
            category: 'plugin-blocks', // Block category. Group blocks together based on common traits E.g. common, formatting, layout widgets, embed.

            // Defines the block within the editor.
            edit: function( props ) {
                return createElement(
                    'p', // Tag type.
                    {
                        className: props.className,  // Class name is generated using the block's name prefixed with wp-block-, replacing the / namespace separator with a single -.
                    },
                    '[Shortcode][/Shortcode]' // Block content
                );
            },

            // Defines the saved block.
            save: function( props ) {
                return createElement(
                    'p', // Tag type.
                    {
                        className: props.className,  // Class name is generated using the block's name prefixed with wp-block-, replacing the / namespace separator with a single -.
                    },
                    '[Shortcode][/Shortcode]' // Block content
                );
            },
        }
    );
})();
```

I am seeing a syntax error within the following code section `<Icon icon={ () => <svg><path d="M5 4v3h5.5v12h3V7H19V4z" /></svg> } />`

The error shows on line 9:

```
Expected an identifier and instead saw '<'.
```

What is the proper way to add a custom svg icon and use it as a Wordpress Block Icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) in your code, then you need to [build the script](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/javascript/versions-and-building/) before using it on "standard" WordPress sites where JSX is not available.

So,

- Either [build the script](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/javascript/js-build-setup/)..
- Or (looking at your code, it's probably easier to just) use (ES5 with) `wp.element.createElement()` and not JSX:

  ```js
  var MyIcon = function () {
    var svg = createElement( 'svg', {},
      createElement( 'path', { d: 'M5 4v3h5.5v12h3V7H19V4z' } )
    );
    return createElement( wp.components.Icon, { icon: svg } );
  };
  ```

  And that would replace the following part:

  ```js
  import { Icon } from '@wordpress/components';

  const MyIcon = () => (
      <Icon icon={ <svg><path d="M5 4v3h5.5v12h3V7H19V4z" /></svg> } />
  );
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this code form works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The Handbook gives the following code,

```
import { Icon } from '@wordpress/components';

const MyIcon = () => (
    <Icon icon={ () => <svg><path d="M5 4v3h5.5v12h3V7H19V4z" /></svg> } />
);
```

You are using,

```
import { Icon } from '@wordpress/components';

const MyIcon = () => (
    <Icon icon={ <svg><path d="M5 4v3h5.5v12h3V7H19V4z" /></svg> } />
);
```

Your code is missing the **() =>** after `<Icon icon={` and before `<svg>`

So, try changing your code to,

```
import { Icon } from '@wordpress/components';

const MyIcon = () => (
    <Icon icon={ () => <svg><path d="M5 4v3h5.5v12h3V7H19V4z" /></svg> } />
);
```

Comment: I still see the same error after changing to the suggested solution. I tried to run the block by editing a post and the defined block does not show up indicating the error. The block works properly when removing the const and changing icon to icon: 'smiley';